# How to filter my database row whit their id?

Tags: python, django, filter

I'm new to python and my question might be so simple and maybe i'm just confusing myself.

I have a postgresql database table with 3 columns, one is id and other two are some information about users.

How can I filter my table so that it give me one of my column's data and its id?

My code is this:

```
def new_item_lessons_learned(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    lessons_learned_form = LessonsLearnedForm(request.POST)
    if lessons_learned_form.is_valid():
        getting_departments_id = Departments.objects.filter(mycolumn=pk)
```

The problem is in `.filter`. I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: What was unclear in the documentation?

Comment: The fact that you're using postgres is irrelevant, it's purely a django orm question (tag removed).

Comment: wrt: the question itself, Django ORM is rather well documented : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/

Comment: `The problem is in` which problem? Error? Wrong data? You don't know how to iterate through queryset?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the given solutions for this:

```
queryset = Departments.objects.filter(pk=1).values('id', 'name')
```

or

```
queryset = Departments.objects.filter(pk=1).only('id', 'name')
```